lsp-mode choosing the wrong project root in multi-language monorepo
I am well aware that this question has been asked a million times.  At least I feel like I've read one million descriptions of this (and just fewer than that in purported solutions).  Nothing has worked so far and I'm losing my mind.
I frequently work in a giant monorepo.  Historically, this was mostly a Golang codebase, so the repo itself has many Go packages under one top-level go.mod and the whole repo lives under $GOPATH.  But by now it additionally has dozens of Rust, TS, Python, whatever projects.  I still have to contribute to many Go projects, so I want to configure lsp-go with gopls to use the whole repo as its workspace (since we don't use Go submodules).  I also work in many Rust projects that are subdirectories of the repo.  So I want to configure many subdirectories of the git repo to be themselves project workspaces for rustic and rust-analyzer.
Here is the start of the section of my emacs configuration that concerns lsp-* things.  In lsp-mode I do have (setq lsp-auto-guess-root nil), which seems to be the most commonly mentioned important setting.  I have also deleted everything that existed with lsp-workspace-folders-remove, and I'm trying to add back (very tediously, I should say) every project I think I'll work with using lsp-workspace-folders-add.
The problem is that if at any time I add the Go workspace that subsumes everything else before I try another project, I get no interactive prompt to set a root for the project in a subdirectory, and it just chooses the git root automatically.  So right now, this happens, I delete the git repo workspace, lsp-workspace-folders-add the correct one, then add back the Go workspace at the git root.
Notably, I use projectile and I understand, but not well enough I guess, that this package plays a large part in this calculation.  This is the configuration at the time of this post, but I've played around with more detailed configuration involving projectile-project-root-functions.  I've tried adding a .projectile in the non-Go projects.  I've tried approaches with a .dir-locals.el file.  All of my efforts have failed.
This can't be that hard, right?  I have really tried to fix this on my own before coming here.  Can someone please point out where I've gone wrong?  Or point me to some material that isn't old enough to mention functions that don't exist any longer, in case I haven't seen that yet?  If projectile is the real problem, I would be so happy to not use it anymore, so that's a possible answer too.

try using '(projectile-root-local projectile-root-top-down projectile-root-top-down-recurring) as projectile-project-root-functions.  I wrap the projectile-find-* functions to use these functions when I want to find something in a nested repo

Thanks for the suggestion.  I don't think I'd tried those options in that order.  It does work much, much better for me because I do my best to avoid the Golang stuff, but it does kind of mess up lsp-go behavior.  It sets the project root to the specific subdirectory like with Rust, but with our project setup that makes it unaware of its dependencies that are in the repo but outside of that workspace.

It would be too much to ask to move to a submodule-based Go project.  I'd really just like it to know with minimal effort on my part that this Golang project is the whole repo.  These Rust projects are the things containing a Cargo.toml.  But now that I think of it, I could probably achieve that by setting some variable equal to a list of files particular to me that convey a project root.  I forget which variable, but I am reminded of something somewhere where that was the answer.

Unrelatedly, I'd also like the Golang lsp setup to not try to watch 15000 directories.  I got it to do that with a dir-locals that sets file-watchers to nil, but that worked when it thought the workspace was the whole thing.

to find rust projects top-down and go projects bottom-up, you could do something like the following (setq projectile-project-root-files-top-down-recurring '("cargo.toml") projectile-project-root-files-bottom-up '("go.work")) but you'd want to set those specifically around lsp--suggest-project-root.  As an example, ccls adds the advice ccls--suggest-project-root

Would love to accept that as answer if you maybe expand on the, "[...] you'd want to set those specifically around lsp--suggest-project-root" part for a dumb-dumb like me.  But to your knowledge, there isn't a more generic way to do this?  I would have to do that for every language/language-specific project file combo?

Actually, now that I think of it, Go is the only problem.  All others would be root-top-down.  How can I say, "always do top-down unless I've opened *.go, then do bottom-up?"
